# How to connect PHP to Oracle9i server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I read some steps about this one but I can't really get it. I'm using wamp server for this with PHP 5.3.5. I tried to use the php_oci8.dll by checking the PHP>PHP extensions>php_oci8 but I get an error saying

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_oci8.dll - The specified module could not be found
```

When I go to the path the php_oci8.dll is there. How can I fix this? Can anybody give me a steps on how can I configure it so that I can connect to a remote server?

Comment: Is this the correct version? check windows.php.net!

Comment: Check the file permissions first.

Comment: @powtac you mean correct version of PHP for windows?

Comment: @symcbean where to find the file permissions?

Comment: @powtac downloaded new php to check. still not working. Same error appears.

Comment: No, latest version of php_oci8.dll!

Comment: Tried and tested what the answer below says. Still doesn't work. Will try again more of those php_oci8.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out! Here's my solution:

1. Install Oracle XE in your PC this will give you the latest oci.dll (not php_oci8.dll)
2. Create a link between your user and the user you will need in connecting to your database.
3. Restart your PC then try running your code if it's not working copy the oci.dll of your 
   Oracle XE (C:\Oracle\OUIHome\bin\oci.dll) then paste it in 9i replacing the old one (make sure to have a backup). then restart your PC.

Works fine on me. Thanks for those who help me in solving this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [download](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) the latest version of the dll here [php_oci8-1.4.1-5.2-vc6-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_oci8-1.4.1-5.2-vc6-x86.zip)

Comment: There are several php_oci8.dll version at the download page, try all.

Comment: Okay I'll try it again the other time. Anyway, will you suggest to download the latest wamp server client? Or I can stick on my version changing the php DLL?

Comment: Probably the WAMP oci8 dll is not tested well by the WAMP team. I would always try to use the latest WAMP. But try it with different versions of the dll...

Comment: haven't tried xampp yet. I already used in working with wamp. Anyway I'm using the same wamp server version, etc on my home PC but the oci_connect as undefined function doesn't appear and I think will work fine here though there are no Oracle database here which why I get a protocol adapter error. Will try reinstalling wamp server, etc the other day. I will keep you updated till I solve the problem.